# How to run websocket tests on circleci

Tags: node.js, typescript, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a node app written in typescript. I am trying to run tests on circle ci. I am able to connect redis server as shown here

```
> env NODE_ENV=test jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --ci

  console.log
    Server is running on PORT 4000

      at Server.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:51:60)

  console.log
    Redis connected!
```

But everything else fails from there.

```
 console.log
    socket1 failed on startup for test 1. Retrying...

      at tests/events.test.ts:147:17

  console.log
    restarted

      at setupSockets (tests/events.test.ts:79:21)

  console.log
    socket1 failed on startup for test 1. Retrying...

      at tests/events.test.ts:147:17

  console.log
    restarted

      at setupSockets (tests/events.test.ts:79:21)
```

This is the package.json to run the tests

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "env NODE_ENV=test jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --ci",
```

These are some of the tests

```
describe("Control test for socket.io", () => {
  test("server should communicate to client.", (done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      sockets[0].once("test", (msg: string) => {
        expect(msg).toBe("Hello World");
        done && done();
      });
      SC[0].emit("test", "Hello World");
    }, 100);
  });

  test("client should communicate to server.", (done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      SC[1].on("test", (msg) => {
        done && done();
        expect(msg).toBe("Hello Server");
      });
      sockets[1].emit("test", "Hello Server");
    }, 100);
  });
});
```